# Tikz line drawing error

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to draw this picture in LaTeX. I am using tikz package for drawing. I am using overleaf to create this document.

[image]

I wrote this code:

```
\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \begin{tikzpicture}
 \draw[->][thick](0,0) to (6,0)
  \draw[->](4,3) to (6,2)
  \end{tikzpicture}
  \caption{Timeline}
  \label{fig:my_label1}
  \end{figure}
```

But it take huge time to compile and after compile throw a error message. ***Timed out. Sorry, your compile took too long to run and timed out. This may be due to a large number of high-res images, or complicated diagrams.***

Now if I draw just one line in between two lines this code run well. But when both the line drawing command activate it give a error.

Can any one tell me what is the problem?

Comment: You need `;` after each line. I.e., `\draw .. ;`. Plus the first one should be `\draw[thick,->] .. ;`.

Comment: @Manuel `\draw[->][thick](0,0) to (6,0);` and `\draw[->,thick](0,0) to (6,0);` do the same, but of course you are right about the `;`s.

Answer (score 2):

As @Manuel stated in a comment, every tikz drawing command must end with a semi-colon `;` or the compiler searches forever trying to find a meaningful interpretation for your command and hence the error message you saw. That said, you can draw these lines in one command using `edge` which allows adding multiple arrow tips. Also, you can add `thick` as a global option, if all your lines should be thick, instead of repeating it.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
 \centering
 \begin{tikzpicture}[thick]
 \path[->] (0,0) edge (6,0) (4,3) edge (6,2);
 \end{tikzpicture}
 \caption{Timeline}
 \label{fig:my_label1}
\end{figure}  

\end{document}
```

> [image]