# Input words within a figure using tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, overleaf

I want to draw this using tikz package of latex.[image]

I already write down the code for that. But the problem is that how could I input the sentence ***Happing Now*** within the picture.

My code is

```
    \begin{frame}{Frame Title}
    \begin{figure}
      \centering
      \begin{tikzpicture}
     \draw[thick][->](0,0) to (4,0);
      \draw[thick][->](2,1.5) to (4,0.5);
      \draw[thick][loosely dotted](4,0) to (5,0);
      \end{tikzpicture}
      \caption{Timeline}
      \label{fig:my_label1}
    \end{figure}
   \end{frame}
```

Comment: palce a `node` at the starting point of the arrow. Read [A very minimal introduction to TikZ](http://cremeronline.com/LaTeX/minimaltikz.pdf) for more.

Comment: please show us mwe (minimal working example), which produce your arrows.

Comment: `\draw[thick][->] (2,1.5) node[anchor=east]{Happing Now} to (4,0.5);`

Comment: @hpekristiansen: The _possible duplicate_ question is about placing text at arbitrary positions, which would be used in this case as well (but would require specifying the coordinate twice). However, I think that that is different than this case as this is about placing text relative to a particular `\draw`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can place a node at the appropriate point, if you replace the `to` syntax with a `--`:

[image]

### Notes:

- You don't need to use `[]` for each option.

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}
 \draw[thick, ->] (0,0) to (4,0);
  \draw[thick, ->]  (2,1.5) -- (4,0.5) node [pos=0, anchor=east] {Happening Now};
  \draw[thick, loosely dotted] (4,0) to (5,0);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can put a node at the beginning of the upper arrow.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

  \begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[thick, ->] (0,0) to (4,0) ;
  \draw[thick, ->]  (2,1.5) node [anchor=east] {Happing Now}  to (4,0.5);
  \draw[thick, loosely dotted](4,0) to (5,0);
  \end{tikzpicture}

  \end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

As suggested by @nidhin:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=0.5cm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}
 \draw[thick][->](0,0) to (4,0);
  \draw[thick][->](2,1.5)node[left]{Happing now} to (4,0.5);
  \draw[thick][loosely dotted](4,0) to (5,0);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

based on answer on the your previous  [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/464421/tikz-line-drawing-error):

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
 \centering
 \begin{tikzpicture}[thick]
 \draw[->]  (0,0) edge (4,0)
            (2,3) node[left] {Happing Now} -- (4,1);
 \draw[thick][loosely dotted] (4,0) -- (5,0);
 \end{tikzpicture}
 \caption{Timeline}
 \label{fig:my_label1}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I think you spelled "Happening Now" wrong? :-). There is a a reference to `[![enter image description here][1]][1]` in the answer. I think you intended to delete that?

Comment: @PeterGrill, thank you to pointing me on this mistake. I still have problems with new interface for loading images ... i delete it, hopefully now is all correct.

Answer (score 2):

Using one command as [my previous answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/464424/59109). Don't use a `to` path if you don't have different angles for `in` and `out`, just `--` or `edge`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}    
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[thick]
 \path[->] (0,0) edge (4,0) (2,1.5)node[label=left:Happening Now]{} edge (4,0.5) (4,0) edge[loosely dotted,-] (5,0);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

> [image]